# Google Sheets activity sending to GA4 with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I have been trying to change my script that used to send to the old UA Google Analytics using the IMAGE() but with the new GA4 you have to send a POST. I tried to use the onOpen(e) with some of the code below but nothing seems to work even though I am not getting any errors. Does anyone know if it is possible to make a call [POST] with this information:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  
  // Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
  var data = {
    "client_id": Utilities.getUuid(),
    "user_id": "webuser",
    "events": ["name", "cve_database"]
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?api_secret=<ID-Here>&measurement_id=<GA4 Acc>', options);
  
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

I tried to get it to update the Google Analytics information so that I can keep track of the users who view the page.

Comment: onOpen is only a simple trigger and probably cannot send UrlFetchApp because it requires permission.

Comment: Do you recommend another way to execute code when someone open the spreadsheet?

Comment: Installable onOpen()

Comment: You can check the executions tab to confirm if there are failed `onOpen()` runs that need authorization. As Cooper mentioned, you can instead create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that uses your own authorization. The Uuids generated will still be random.

Comment: Still no go, I tried to create the trigger but it won't execute, I also tried to take the same code and put it on my webserver and send POST for GA4 servers and nothing seems to show up. It only seems to work from the Event Builder. Do you all know where I can find someone to build the code for $$?